# API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials : wso2 IOT server

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-iot

I am using siddhi on android and have registered emulator with IOT server, but the issue is that sometimes it works but sometimes it gives an error like this

```sh
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,331] [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,331] [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,331] [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,334] [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,399] [IoT-Core]  INFO - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator} Invalid OAuth Token : Access Token c2fbbf1c-437f-347b-a233-0cfe3d58156c expired.
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,399] [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,423] [IoT-Core] ERROR - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl} Invalid OAuth Token : Invalid access token
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,426] [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,434] [IoT-Core]  INFO - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator} Invalid OAuth Token : Access Token c2fbbf1c-437f-347b-a233-0cfe3d58156c expired.
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,434] [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,443] [IoT-Core] ERROR - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl} Invalid OAuth Token : Invalid access token
[2018-02-08 16:24:21,445] [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials
```

my guess is that it is happening because each time I launch emulator the credentials change for the phone

It shows me that agent is not connected

[image]

but Agent shows that sync was ok

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I am using a real device now , i had issues when emulator was running on workstation#1  and i wanted to send streams from  workstation #2 to the emulator. I did port forwarding as well. In my opinion the agent works well on real device. The answer to your question: I was not able to solve this issue on emulator.